# CFStringCreateWithCString is paired with a CFRelease，but it crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I placed a pair of CFStringCreateWithCString and CFRelease in a for loop

```
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < tempDict.count; i ++) {
        NSString *key = tempDict.allKeys[i];
        NSString *numStr = tempDict[key];
        CFStringRef numValue = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, [numStr UTF8String], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        if (!ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phone, numValue, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL)) {
            DLog(@"add multivalue failed. index: %i", i);
        }
        CFRelease(numValue);
    }
```

The CFRelease caused my app to crash, and console logged:

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14fa4410
```

If I comment out the CFRelease, it works fine. But the crash is not like an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, it's like this:
[image]

[image]

But when I click two rows bellow it

[image]

It tells me the error is here, the end of this code block
[image]

My question is:

1, Why does it crash with a "-[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17065170" error? In CoreFoundation, create and release functions should be paired, isn't it?

2, Why does the compiler think the error is in the last line? First, is't an ABAddressBookRef, not a CFString, and the console log is clear: -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance, and second, the app goes right after I commented the CFRelease in the previous for loop, so I think if there is an error, it can't be with the CFRelease(addressBook) in any way.

3, What does this error mean? It's an EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, but we saw a lot of  "message sent to deallocated instance" errors marked with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Hope some one could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the `CFString` object anyway, as you can bridge between `NSString` and `CFStringRef`:

```
for (NSString *key in [tempDict allKeys]) {
        NSString *numStr = tempDict[key];
        if (!ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phone, (__bridge CFStringRef)numStr, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL)) {
            DLog(@"add multivalue failed. index: %i", i);
        }
}
```